# multiprocessing.Pool.map throws MemoryError

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning

I am rewriting a Reinforcement Learning Framework from serial code execution to parallel (multiprocessing) to reduce training time. It works but after a few hours of training a `MemoryError` is thrown. I tried adding `gc.collect` after each loop with no change.

Here's the for loop, that utilizes multiprocessing:

```
for episode in episodes:
    env.episode = episode
    flex_list = [0,1,2]                                                                                          
    for machine in env.list_of_machines:                                                                            
        flex_plan = []                                                                                              
        for time_step in range(0,env.steplength):
            flex_plan.append(random.choice(flex_list))
        machine.flex_plan = flex_plan
    env.current_step = 0                                                                                            
    steps = []
    state = env.reset(restricted=True)                                                                              
    steps.append(state)

    # multiprocessing part, has condition to use a specific amount of CPUs or 'all' of them
    ####################################################
    func_part = partial(parallel_pool, episode=episode, episodes=episodes, env=env, agent=agent, state=state, log_data_qvalues=log_data_qvalues, log_data=log_data, steps=steps)
    if CPUs_used == 'all':
        mp.Pool().map(func_part, range(env.steplength-1))
    else:
        mp.Pool(CPUs_used).map(func_part, range(env.steplength-1))
    ############################################################
    # model is saved periodically, not only in the end
    save_interval = 100 #set episode interval to save models
    if (episode + 1) % save_interval == 0:
        agent.save_model(f'models/model_{filename}_{episode + 1}')
        print(f'model saved at episode {episode + 1}')

    plt.close()
    gc.collect()
```

Output after 26 episodes of training:

```
Episode: 26/100   Action: 1/11    Phase: 3/3    Measurement Count: 231/234   THD fake slack: 0.09487   Psoll: [0.02894068 0.00046048 0.         0.        ]    Laptime: 0.181
Episode: 26/100   Action: 1/11    Phase: 3/3    Measurement Count: 232/234   THD fake slack: 0.09488   Psoll: [0.02894068 0.00046048 0.         0.        ]    Laptime: 0.181
Episode: 26/100   Action: 1/11    Phase: 3/3    Measurement Count: 233/234   THD fake slack: 0.09489   Psoll: [0.02894068 0.00046048 0.         0.        ]    Laptime: 0.179
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/train.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/train.py", line 77, in main
    duration = cf.training(episodes, env, agent, filename, topology=topology, multi_processing=multi_processing, CPUs_used=CPUs_used)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\RL_framework\help_functions\custom_functions.py", line 166, in training
    save_interval = parallel_training(range(episodes), env, agent, log_data_qvalues, log_data, filename, CPUs_used)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\RL_framework\help_functions\custom_functions.py", line 81, in parallel_training
    mp.Pool().map(func_part, range(env.steplength-1))
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve memory issues problems while multiprocessing using Pool.map()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429368/how-to-solve-memory-issues-problems-while-multiprocessing-using-pool-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you create processes in the loop, I believe your memory is choked because the processes you create are left hanging after they finish running.

From the [documentaion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

> Warning: multiprocessing.pool objects have internal resources that
>   need to be properly managed (like any other resource) by using the
>   pool as a context manager or by calling close() and terminate()
>   manually. Failure to do this can lead to the process hanging on
>   finalization. Note that is not correct to rely on the garbage colletor
>   to destroy the pool as CPython does not assure that the finalizer of
>   the pool will be called (see object.**del**() for more information).

I suggest you try to refactor your code a little:

```
# set the CPUs_used to a desired number or None to use all available CPUs
with mp.Pool(processes=CPUs_used) as p:
    p.map(func_part, range(env.steplength-1))
```

Or you can manually `.close()` and `.join()`, whichever suits your coding style best.